# Does Ontario cap the eligible amount of tax deductible donation to 75% of the net income for 2024?

Tags: income-tax, canada, ontario, tax-credit, charitable-contributions

I googled this for quite a while but I couldn't find anything from official Canadian government sources other than 5.05% on the 1st 200$ and 11.16% on the next ones... where am I supposed to look? I'm making a tax credit estimation tool so I thought it would be great if I can include a link to a government website

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the amount is 'generally' limited to 75%, per CRA website.

https://www.canada.ca/en/revenue-agency/services/tax/individuals/topics/about-your-tax-return/tax-return/completing-a-tax-return/deductions-credits-expenses/line-34900-donations-gifts.html

I'll caution that you have to be very careful about how you present the surety of what could be considered tax advice. Things get very complicated very quickly, and there may be unexpected interactions between various sections of the Income Tax Act. Don't overpromise on accuracy. As you already said - tying everything back to a government statement would be a good start.

For future questions like this, the CRA's repository of information is quite good, though their search function is lacking. I found the above link to confirm in about 10 seconds, by entering this string into google:

```
site:canada.ca charitable contribution limit
```

You can perform similar searches for other questions, though bear in mind if you are not familiar with the material, you could easily miss relevant ideas. For example - the different provincial implications vs federal implications.

Comment: Thanks! So this seems to be the rule, with some exceptions (e.g. Quebec provincial tax credit)?

Comment: Would it be a good idea to add "this is only a ballpark estimate, consult a real tax expert for more accurate information"?

Comment: @qwerty_99 Do you mind my asking what your general intent would be in providing the information? Is this going to be a 'destination' website that you try to draw traffic to, or is it going to be a way to build online presence for your accounting firm etc., or is it going to try to sell a product, such as tax software? I have a lot of thoughts about the lack of independent tax guidance in Canada, but one of the real problems is simply how much personalized attention is really needed to truly add value. A self-learner can answer most tax questions themselves, with enough effort.

Comment: Most people however really do need their hand held to cover the basics, because there really isn't such a thing as 'universal tax education' in Canada. I enjoy helping people who have questions in this area, and it would be commendable to try and build a service that offers the information more broadly. But then the ultimate conundrum is: would you just be duplicating the CRA's guidance on these things, because you need to be so broad and comprehensive? And if not, would you risk over-stating your teaching by not covering the basis, resulting in misinformation [maybe even being liable].

Comment: I'm working on the website of a non profit, and I'm trying to add a tax credit estimation tool similar to this one https://www.canadahelps.org/en/tax-time/